# Problemas ao realizar INSERT (PDO)

Tags: php, array, pdo, back-end

Boa tarde!

Estou encontrando problemas para realizar o seguinte Insert:

```
function cadastro($usuario,$senha,$status){
    $pdo = con();

    $usuario = "Matheus";
    $senha = "123";
    $status = 3;

    $inf = [
        'usuario' => $usuario,
        'senha' => $senha,
        'status' => $status,
    ];

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario";
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($inf);
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Desde já agradecido!

Answer (score 1):

Cara, o erro muito provavelmente, está na sua query. Você esta tentando substituir o `:usuario` por um array que na verdade deveria ser uma string.

Exemplo:

```
$inf = [
    'usuario' => 'Matheus'
];
```

o `prepare` vai substituir o `:usuario` por 'Matheus'. Da forma que voce esta fazendo, ele tenta substituir `:usuario` por um array.

Acredito que desta forma deve funcionar:

```
function cadastro($usuario, $senha, $status)
{
    $pdo = con();
    $inf = [
        'usuario' => 'Matheus',
        'senha' => '123',
        'status' => 3
    ];
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha AND status = :status";
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($inf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Matheus, como coloquei no comentário, caso sua dúvida seja de cadastro, abaixo uma sugestão de alteração da sua função.

```
function cadastro($usuario, $senha, $status) {
    $pdo = con();

    $usuario = "Matheus";
    $senha = "123";
    $status = 3;

    $inf = [
        'usuario' => $usuario,
        'senha' => $senha,
        'status' => $status,
    ];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha, status) VALUES(:usuario,:senha,:status)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);        
    $stmt->execute($inf);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, na verdade meu erro foi não ter colocado a função inteira, existe uma parte da função que faz exatamente esse INSERT que você comentou, mas antes de fazer o esse INSERT eu preciso fazer esse SELECT apenas com o nome do usuário para saber se já existe um usuário igual.